# Find all skew-symmetric matrices given their anti-commutator with a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $S$ be a skew-symmetric matrix and $J$ a symmetric matrix. Is it possible to find all skew-symmetric matrices $\Omega$ satisfying $$S = J\Omega + \Omega J$$ in terms of $S$ and $J$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorizing the equation yields
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(S) &= {\rm vec}(J\Omega I) + {\rm vec}(I\Omega J) \cr
s &= (I\otimes J + J\otimes I)\,\omega \,\,{\dot =}\,\, M\omega \cr
\omega &= M^+s + (I-M^+M)\,a \cr
\Omega &= {\rm Mat}\big(M^+s + (I-M^+M)\,a\big) \cr
}$$ where ${\rm Mat}()$ is the inverse of the ${\rm vec}()$ operation, $\otimes$ represents the Kronecker product, $M^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $M$, and $a$ is an arbitrary vector.

If $M$ is full rank then $(I-M^+M)=0$ and there is only one solution, otherwise there are an infinite number, i.e. a solution for each $a$ vector.

Comment: What do you mean by vectorizing the equation?

Comment: Did you assume that matrices are $3 \times 3$ so that there's a direct correspondence between vectors and skew-symmetric matrices?

Comment: @greg Can we express the constraint on $J$ that makes $M$ full rank.